# Number datatype in informatica is converting the number into exponential form

Tags: type-conversion, informatica, informatica-powercenter

My problem is that informatica mapping is converting a number of the form 8000196005072015 to the form 8.000196005072015e+15.The precession of the number datatype for this field is set at 50 and its scale is set to 0. How can I prevent this from happening without trimming the data(8000196005072015).

Thanks

Comment: the datatype of the port is number in flat file and decimal in source qualifier.

Comment: No data was trimmed in your example - 8000196005072015 == 8.000196005072015e+15, only the notation is different. However, see the answer below to learn what you need to do to actually be working with decimal values.

Comment: Where do you see the exponential value? Is it saved in the target in this format?

Answer (score 4):

There is an important difference between the `decimal` and `double` datatypes in PowerCenter:

- `decimal` – a fixed-point representation of real numbers,
- `double` – a floating-point representation of real numbers.

However, defining a `decimal` port does not automatically mean the Integration Service will treat values passing though this port as fixed-point numbers.

```
Port datatype | Precision |  High Precision
              |           |   Off  |   On
---------------------------------------------
decimal       |   0-28    | double | decimal
decimal       |  over 28  | double | double
```

To actually work with `decimal` values the following conditions have to be met:

1. the datatype of the port is `decimal` *and*
2. the precision of the port is 28 or less *and*
3. the session option *Enable high precision* is enabled.

Comment: This is helpful information. Any idea what the rationale is behind treating `decimal(x,y)` data as `double` in most cases?

Comment: @WAF No, I could never understand it and I find it very confusing.